# Regression in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, linear-regression

just wonder anybody can give me an insight about regression code in tensorflow.

I have code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = numpy.random

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# Training Data
Y1, T1, X1 = numpy.genfromtxt('data7.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(2,3,4), unpack=True, dtype=None)
train_X = X1
train_T = T1
train_Y = Y1
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
T = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
a1 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight1")
a2 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight2")
a3 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight3")
a4 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight4")

# Construct a linear model
# pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)
hyp1 = tf.multiply(X, tf.add(a1,tf.add(tf.multiply(a2,X),tf.multiply(a3,tf.log(X)))))
hyp2 = tf.add(1.0, tf.multiply(a4, tf.add(T, -25.0)))
pow_ac_pred = tf.multiply(hyp1, hyp2)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pow_ac_pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

# Gradient descent

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y, t) in zip(train_X, train_Y, train_T):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y, T:t})

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y, T:train_T})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                "a1=", sess.run(a1), "a2=", sess.run(a2), "a3", sess.run(a3), "a4", sess.run(a4))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y, T:train_T})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost, "a1=", sess.run(a1), "a2=", sess.run(a2), \
          "a3", sess.run(a3), "a4", sess.run(a4), '\n')
```

I am giving data for X, Y and T. However, the logs for each epoch give me 'nan' which does not make very much sense to me. 
The model is to predict power of ac from solar panel by using irradiation and temperature of solar modules. 
The relationship between those variables is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg7ok.png)
P_ac = G*(a1 + a2*G + a3 *log(G)) * (1 + a4*(Tm - 25))
where p_ac is power output, G is irradiation and Tm is module temperature.
If i am completely wrong to solve the problem. Can anyone give me a right way to solve this? 
Thanks

Comment: And X > 0 resp. G > 0 all the time?

Comment: Yes! X>0 and G>0 all the time.

Comment: try `tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(...` if the values get too large to avoid `tf.reduce_sum`

Comment: Still not working...  i dont think the values are particularly large.